# ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype

Tags: oracle

I have a column in Oracle to store comments of `Nvarchar2(2000)`. When a user tries to enter beyond 2000 characters, I get the following error:

```
ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype.
```

The `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` parameter is having `AL16UTF16` value.

Is there any way to increase the size to accept up to 6000 characters? My column already has lots of contents, so not sure if I will be able to change the datatype from `NVarchar(2000)` to any other.

Comment: What is the characterset of your database? Do you need to use nvarchar2s?

Answer (score 14):

Unless you use Oracle 12c, it's not possible to store more than 2000 characters, see the datatypes description here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm

Instead, you should use the NCLOB datatype.

If you use 12c, check: http://dbasolved.com/2013/06/26/change-varchar2-to-32k-12c-edition/

Comment: Sadly we encountered to this limit, in our case we needed 3000 normal characters on 3000 bytes, but some of things were stored on 2 bytes. As workaround we had to convert, since it didn't allow 6000 characters.