# Installing zabbix with Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, zabbix

I'm installing Zabbix 3.2.1 I run a demo without problem using mysql but know I'm configuring a more proper server for this using our Oracle instance.

I'm following the official guide here https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/appendix/install/db_scripts but it seems to be incorrect.

First I had to change the images.sql file to change the target directory to /tmp/zabbix_images instead of the default one. Then I had to give a couple of grant to zabbix user on the db like "create any directory" and "drop any directory".

But also then, when I try to run the @images.sql file I got the following compilation errors:

```
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

    LOAD_IMAGE(1,1,'Cloud_(128)','png_modern/Cloud_(128).png');
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00905: object ZABBIX.LOAD_IMAGE is invalid
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 3, column 2:
PLS-00905: object ZABBIX.LOAD_IMAGE is invalid
ORA-06550: line 3, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 2:
PLS-00905: object ZABBIX.LOAD_IMAGE is invalid
ORA-06550: line 4, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 5, column 2:
PLS-00905: object ZABBIX.LOAD_IMAGE is invalid
ORA-06550: line 5, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 2:
PLS-00905: object ZABBIX.LOAD_IMAGE is invalid
ORA-06550: line 6, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 7, column 2:
PLS-00905: object ZABBIX.LOAD_IMAGE is invalid
ORA-06550: line 7, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 8, column 2:
PLS-00905: object ZABBIX.LOAD_IMAGE is invalid
ORA-06550: line 8, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 9, column 2:
PLS-00905: object ZABBIX.LOAD_IMAGE is invalid
ORA-06550: line 9, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 10, column 2:
PLS-00905: object ZABBIX.LOAD_IMAGE is invalid
ORA-06550: line 10, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 11, column 2:
PLS-00905: object ZABBIX.LOAD_IMAGE is invalid
ORA-06550: line 11, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

How can I solve this? Or can I just ignore it being only part of the lines?

Thanks,
Michele.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the previous command, the execution of schema.sql.

Running that file I got this error:

```
        description              nvarchar2(2048) DEFAULT ''                ,
                                                 *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype
```

That is then reflected on other lines. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294028/ora-00910-specified-length-too-long-for-its-datatype) other question, I see that this is a limitation on the number of character that can be stored, as I'm using oracle 11.2.0 and not 12. But from the [requirements](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/installation/requirements) it was supposed to work.